# How to properly handle create and update for realm.io relationships

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've got two `RLMObjects`:

```
class Timeline: RLMObject {

    dynamic var entries = RLMArray(objectClassName: Entry.className())
    dynamic var id          = 0
    dynamic var title       = ""
    dynamic var coverPhoto  = ""
    dynamic var body        = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
        }
}

class Entry: RLMObject {


    dynamic var id          :Int = 0
    dynamic var timelineID  :Int = 0
    dynamic var name        :String = ""
    dynamic var caption     :String = ""
    dynamic var body        :String = ""
    dynamic var imageURL    :String = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a To-Many relationship between a Timeline and an Entry. A timeline has many Entries.

the JSON fetch and assignment of my timelines works just fine, they are being fetched and set with:

```
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
Timeline.createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject(timelineObject)
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

My problem arises when I'm trying to fetch the entries (which is a separate JSON request/response) for a given timeline and set them.

Fetching and creating them like this works just fine:

```
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
Entry.createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject(entryObject)
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

But of course that doesn't associate them with my Timeline object. So then I tried to get my Timeline object and then adding the Entry object to my timeline by doing:

```
let timelineObject = Timeline(forPrimaryKey: id)
timelineObject.entries.addObject(entryObject)
```

(inside of a transaction ofc).

This works fine for the initial fetch. But when I try to refetch your data, you get the following RLMException:

```
'RLMException', reason: 'Can't set primary key property 'id' to existing value 59.'
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? It seems like there should be an instance method on RLMObject that creates or updates a product, like it's class method does?

**Solution**
As segiddins comment suggests, you add the return from the class method: createOrUpdate... and then add that return to your object (in my case, the `timelineObject.entries.addObject(entryReturn)`.

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()                        
realm.beginWriteTransaction()

for entry in json["entries"] {

...
//Process and map the JSON
...
let entryReturn = Entry.createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject(entryObject)
timelineObject.entries.addObject(entryReturn)

}
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

Comment: try adding the Entry object that gets returned from the createOrUpdate call?

Comment: It was as simple as that segiddins! Thanks. Do you wan't to make it an answer, so it can get upvoted?

Ps. What an awesome framework! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the `Entry` object that gets returned from the `createOrUpdate` call.